# Rust define trait interface for any type?

Tags: serialization, rust, gpu, traits

I am building a rendering engine, one thing I want is to handle mangagement of arbitrary mesh data, regardless of representation.

My idea was, define a trait the enforces a function signature and then serialization can be handled by the user while I handle all the gpu stuff. This was the trait I made:

```rust
pub enum GpuAttributeData
{
    OwnedData(Vec<Vec<i8>>, Vec<u32>),
}
pub trait GpuSerializable
{
    fn serialize(&self) -> GpuAttributeData;
}
```

So very simple, give me a couple of arrays.

When i tested things inside the crate it worked, but I moved my example outside the crate, i.e. I have this snippet in an example:

```rust
impl <const N : usize> GpuSerializable for [Vertex; N]
{
    fn serialize(&self) -> GpuAttributeData
    {
        let size = size_of::<Vertex>() * self.len();
        let data = unsafe {
            let mut data = Vec::<i8>::with_capacity(size);
            copy_nonoverlapping(
                self.as_ptr() as *const i8, data.as_ptr() as *mut i8, size);
            data.set_len(size);
            data
        };

        // let indices : Vec<usize> = (0..self.len()).into_iter().collect();
        let indices = vec![0, 1, 2];
        let mut buffers :Vec<Vec<i8>> = Vec::new();
        buffers.push(data);

        return GpuAttributeData::OwnedData(buffers, indices);
    }
}
```

Which gives me this error:

```rust
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
  --> examples/01_spinning_triangle/main.rs:41:1
   |
41 | impl <const N : usize> GpuSerializable for [Vertex; N]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------
   | |                                          |
   | |                                          this is not defined in the current crate because arrays are always foreign
   | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
   |
   = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

This utterly breaks my design. The whole point of what I am trying to achieve is, anyone anywhere should be able to implement that trait, inside or outside any crate, to be able to serialize whatever data they have, in whatever esoteric format it is.

Can I somehow bypass this restriction? If not, is there another way I could enforce at runtime "give me an object that has this function signature among its methods"?

Comment: What is the definition of `Vertex` in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust has the [orphan rule](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/01/14/little-orphan-impls/), which says that any implementation of a trait on a type must exist in the same crate as at least one of the trait or the type.  In other words, both types can't be foreign.  (It's a bit more complex than this -- for example, you can implement a foreign generic trait on a foreign type if a generic type argument to the generic trait is a type declared in the local crate.)

This is why you frequently see so-called "newtypes" in Rust, which are typically unit structs with a single member, whose sole purpose is to implement a foreign trait on a foreign type.  The newtype lives in the same crate as the implementation, so the compiler accepts the implementation.

This could be realized in your example with a newtype around the array type:

```
#[repr(transparent)]
struct VertexArray<const N: usize>(pub [Vertex; N]);

impl<const N: usize> Deref for VertexArray<N> {
    type Target = [Vertex; N];
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<const N: usize> DerefMut for VertexArray<N> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.0
    }
}

impl<const N: usize> GpuSerializable for VertexArray<N> {
    // ...
}
```

Note that because of `#[repr(transparent)]`, the layout of both `VertexArray<N>` and `[Vertex; N]` are guaranteed to be identical, meaning you can transmute between them, or references to them.  This allows you to, for example, reborrow a `&[Vertex; N]` as a `&VertexArray<N>` safely, which means you can store all of your data as `[Vertex; N]` and borrow it as the newtype at zero cost whenever you need to interact with something expecting an implementation of `GpuSerializable`.

```
impl<const N: usize> AsRef<VertexArray<N>> for [Vertex; N] {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &VertexArray<N> {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(self) }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was try the definition of trait and implementation in different crates, it somehow is compiling for me https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aeb702bbe188de3f8ce140d0339af69c, am I missing something wrt to this question?

Comment: @AshishSingh That example has the trait and the impl in separate _modules,_ but both modules are within the same crate.

Comment: what is the purpose of this? if you can easily bypass it by adding a little bit of wrapping clutter, why not allow implementation right away?

Comment: @Makogan Because then a type defined by a crate implementing a new trait would be a breaking change because it could break compilation of third-party crates that also happened to define that trait for that type.